# File Not Found error when trying to access file using Http get Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am trying read some configuration data from an Env file. But its always saying file not found.

Here is my code snippet I'm trying

```
this.http.get('src/assets/env/env.json').pipe(map( res => res.json())).pipe(catchError((error: any): any => {
    console.log('Configuration file "env.json" could not be read');
    resolve(true);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
})
```

And in my Angular.json file I have specified this under assets

For build

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/assets/env/env.json",
    "src/web.config"
],
```

Under Test

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/assets/env"
],
```

But when running the application I am getting this error

> http://localhost:4200/src/assets/env/env.json 404 (Not Found)
>
> Configuration file "env.json" could not be read

This is how my application folder structure

[image]

My above code for reading JSON file is at app.config.ts

I really believe its something with the relative path. But honestly I didnt get how to make it correctly. Please help

Comment: have you tried `this.http.get('assets/env/env.json')`? Also, you can just use `import('assets/env/env.json')` and have it imported at build time. Also you seem to either be using a very old angular version or following a very old guide `res.json()` has been removed long ago

Comment: Thanks friend.. I was using some code I copied from a tutorial. If you dont mind it will be great if you can post how to use that, as an answer

Comment: @PoulKruijt Its working fine when I use the path as you specified. Thanks a lot . But could you please share the correct way than I am trying.. I mean the new way...